# Is there a way to find which region BorderLayout has docked a user draggable JToolBar

Tags: java, swing, border-layout, jtoolbar

I have user draggable `JToolBars` added to the NORTH, EAST and WEST regions of a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`. When the app exits I would like to save the region that the user has docked the `JToolBars` to, in order to respect this preference on next app launch.

I've examined the property change listener approach, and tried obtaining the instance of `BorderLayout` on the `JPanel` and inquiring as to the Constraints each added component has, but am unable to find the right info. I've trawled the source code too, and most of the user dragging appears to be delegated to the UI in effect and am struggling to keep context as I read through it all.

Any Swing aficionados know the answer here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just use `ContainerListener`

```
public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e);
```

for your container to get the docking event?

Comment: Seem to work. Tested with `System.out.println(((BorderLayout)e.getContainer().getLayout()).getConstraints(toolBar));` :-D

Comment: Me too, thanks both: in the ContainerListener.componentAdded method, by using the BorderLayout.getConstraints(e.getChild()) method it returns the region, i.e. North, West etc.

Comment: @Hamish258 http://java-sl.com/tip_multiple_floatable_toolbars.html this also could be useful. You can do the same on LayoutManager level

Comment: @StanislavL btw is that a typo in the `prefferedLayoutSize` method, perhaps means `preferredLayoutSize`? Thanks